# Download file from Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am building a bot for Slack and trying to download images from im with a user.

The workflow looks like:
- User uploads file to bots' im
- The bot receives an event and downloads files (in 2 resolutions)

When I upload a file to a chat with the bot - everything is ok, I can download files.

When another user uploads a file - I get an HTML page with authorization form. Tried to download with curl, but have the same problem:

```sh
 curl --location --request GET 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T45M3A4BU-FS9CJQPLH/screenshot_2020-01-13_at_11.23.10.png' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xoxp-...'
```

Works with my files and doesn't work with other users.

The bot has scopes: `files:read`, `files:write:user`

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the `xoxb-` token (Bot token) instead of the `xoxp-` token (User token)

Token from user A cannot download files from the chat between the bot and user B.